# How to check if a string contains a continous integer

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have rows of information, and need to extract just the integers from them.

Ex:

```
A1 : 130001    
A2 : hello_24.02_75_150001  
A3 : 650000_take:away  
A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105
```

I want to take only the six digit numbers (130000, 150001, 650000, 800000). How can I get only those?

I tried `IsNumeric(number)` and

```
If Regex.IsMatch(number, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then

...

End If
```

Comment: Posted a regexp solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a user defined formula in VBA. Place the foloowing code in a new module and call it as a function in Excel as `=Extract6Digits(A1)`

```
Function Extract6Digits(Number As String)

Dim varCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim varOutput As String
Dim varTemp As String

varCount = 0
varTemp = ""

For i = 1 To Len("" & Number & "")

    If Asc(Mid("" & Number & "", i, 1)) >= 48 And Asc(Mid("" & Number & "", i, 1)) <= 57 Then

        varCount = varCount + 1
        varTemp = varTemp & Mid("" & Number & "", i, 1)

    Else

        varCount = 0
        varTemp = ""

    End If

    If varCount = 6 Then

        If varOutput = "" Then

            varOutput = varTemp

        Else

            varOutput = varOutput & "," & varTemp

        End If

        varCount = 0
        varTemp = ""

    End If

Next

Extract6Digits = varOutput

End Function
```

This is by no means the most efficient method, but it works

Comment: surprisingly, as per my testing, this is the fastest method of the ones here posted up to date

Comment: Glad I could help mate,  I would have a assumed a regex to be faster also.

Answer (score 2):

I thought you wanted `regexp` solution ;)

Is this what you want?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim s As String
    Dim regEx, Match, matches
    Dim rngRange As Range

    s = "A123456X hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 6500000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 987654"

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "(^|\D)(\d{6})(\D|$)"
        .Global = True

        Set matches = .Execute(s)

        If matches.Count > 0 Then
            For Each Match In matches
                Debug.Print Match.SubMatches(1)
                '~~> Result
                '123456
                '150001
                '800000
                '987654
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this works but (sadly) is the slowest one. I said sadly since in my opinion this is the most elegant solution. could be that `For Each Match In matches` loop adding sensitive time?

Comment: Slowest? How? Try timing it with a string which is 2k long ;)

Comment: well my tests were with one column of 12k rows whose cells were filled with a string like "A2" from OP question. I didn't test with a longer string, but I believe you by word!

Comment: I couldn't resist and made a test! I filled each cell of a 1k rows column with a 3k long word (I repeated the "A2" OP's pattern as needed). I found that AranDG code is twice faster than yours (and giving the same results...). Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I am not sure how are you using it. I am out at the moment. Posting from phone. Let me come back and post my findings :)

Comment: if you don't mind I could edit your post and at the bottom add code about how I use it. or make a new answer (which is not however)

Comment: I would recommend adding it to your question on how are you testing both methods

Comment: should I start a question anew?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Sub test()
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        totallen = Len(Range("A" & i).Value)
        For j = 1 To totallen
            thischar = Mid(Range("A" & i), j, 1)
            Select Case thischar
            Case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "0"
                If IsNumeric(Mid(Range("A" & i), j, 6)) = True Then
                    Range("B" & i).Value = Mid(Range("A" & i), j, 6)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End Select
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: this only catches the first occurrence of a 6 digit number

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Function GetSixDigits(s As String) As String

    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim strArr() As String
    strArr = Split(s, "_")

    For intIndex = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)
        If Len(strArr(intIndex)) = 6 And IsNumeric(strArr(intIndex)) Then
            GetSixDigits = strArr(intIndex)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: in such a string as "hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105" this functions only catches the "800000" number

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Siddharth Rout and AranDG answers, I've done some performance testing.

Test of Siddharth Rout's solution

```
'----------------------------------------
'adapted from Siddharth Rout's answer
' works
Sub Sample()
    Dim regEx, Match, matches
    Dim rngRange As Range, cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim mytime As Long

    mytime = Timer

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "(^|\D)(\d{6})(\D|$)"
        .Global = True

        For Each cell In Range("A1:A12000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
            Set matches = .Execute(cell.Value)

            If matches.Count > 0 Then
                i = 0
                For Each Match In matches
                    i = i + 1
                    cell.Offset(, i) = Match.SubMatches(1)
                Next
            End If
        Next cell

    End With
    MsgBox Timer - mytime

End Sub
'----------------------------------------
```

Test of AranDG's solution:

```
'----------------------------------------
'adapted form AranDG
' works
Sub Sample4()
Dim cell As Range
Dim arr As Variant
Dim mytime As Long

mytime = Timer

For Each cell In Range("A1:A12000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
'    cell.Offset(, 1) = Extract6Digits(cell.Value)
    arr = Extract6Digits(cell.Value)
    cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
Next cell

MsgBox Timer - mytime
End Sub

Function Extract6Digits(Number As String) As Variant

Dim varCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim varOutput As String
Dim varTemp As String

varCount = 0
varTemp = ""

For i = 1 To Len("" & Number & "")

    If Asc(Mid("" & Number & "", i, 1)) >= 48 And Asc(Mid("" & Number & "", i, 1)) <= 57 Then

        varCount = varCount + 1
        varTemp = varTemp & Mid("" & Number & "", i, 1)

    Else

        varCount = 0
        varTemp = ""

    End If

    If varCount = 6 Then

        If varOutput = "" Then

            varOutput = varTemp

        Else

            varOutput = varOutput & "," & varTemp

        End If

        varCount = 0
        varTemp = ""

    End If

Next

Extract6Digits = Split(varOutput, ",")

End Function
'----------------------------------------
```

And I run them with active sheet column "A" filled from "A1" to "A1000" with the following string:

```
hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105  hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105  hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105  hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105  hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105 hello_24.02_75_150001 A3 : 650000_take:away A4 : computer_800000_24.01.105
```

Comment: Don't open with "this is not an answer".  It provides two answers to the question, and compares them.  The fact that the answers came from other users should be noted, but you're still providing an answer.

Comment: My first concern was not to steal any credits from people who gave real answers. That said, if you really think it is an answer I'd expect focus on being it useful or not whether on which word I chose to begin it with. I feel a lot of respect for people here who take their time to help other people and never care about how they write things but only if they add something or not.

Comment: There's a flag type named _not an answer_ that feeds your post into the Low Quality Posts queue, where reviewers can choose to delete it.  If you start your post with "this is not an answer", it's very likely to be deleted in review.  Teepeemm's just trying to help you keep your answer from being deleted.

Comment: I appreciate both your explanation and the "possible" help try by Teepeemm. I also think help cab be given with a plain comment without down-voting the answer... as for my not-answer deletion risk: I'm confident that anyone who decides to delete any answer is going to read it through first. but it's very likely to be deleted since nobody till now happened to find it useful (no up-votes). that's life!

Comment: It has, indeed, landed in the deletion queue. Would it hurt so much to click the [edit] link below the Answer and make some small changes to reflect how it helps in the discussion :-)? There *are* "robo-reviewers" who will delete based on that one statement, without reading further. I'm not one of them, but it almost happened to me...

Comment: See the simple edit that makes answers like this helpful. Now... if you included the results of the testing, that would be really helpful!